# Object Orientated PHP SELECT: One column and display other three columns

Tags: php

I want to display treeid, treelatitude and treelongitude by selecting the treecondition column.

When I POST "healthy" I want to display treeid 4,6 & 7, And If I POST "Balanced" want to get treeid 1 & 8. How can I get it?

In my below code I can only able to display any of them

Please help to where exactly I am getting wrong in my code

```
Treeid   treelatitude  treelongitude  treeCondition
 1       12.33          17.22           Balanced
 2       12.33          17.22           Healthy
 3       12.33          17.33           Dieseased
 4       13.44          17.55           Healthy
 5       11.32          17.66           Imbalanced
 6       12.33          18.33           Healthy
 7       14.44          18.44           Healthy
 8       11.22          17.22           Balanced

 <?php

 define('__ROOT__', dirname(dirname(__FILE__))); 
 require_once(__ROOT__.'/public_html/Config.php');


 // Connecting to mysql database
  $mysqli = new mysqli(DB_HOST, DB_USER, DB_PASSWORD, DB_DATABASE);

  // json response array
  $response = array();


    $sq = "SELECT treeid, treelatitude, treelongitude FROM tree WHERE treecondition = ?";

    if (isset($_POST['treecondition'])) {

   // receiving the post params

      $treecondition = $_POST['treecondition'];

     // get the tree details for google map marker
     if($stmt = $mysqli->prepare($sq)){

         $stmt->bind_param("s", $treecondition);

       $stmt->execute();



         if ($stmt->num_rows) {


           while($tree = $stmt->fetch()) {

     $treeItem = array();

     $treeItem["treeid"] = $tree['treeid'];
     $treeItem["treelatitude"] = $tree['treelatitude'];
     $treeItem["treelongitude"] = $tree['treelongitude'];
     $response[] = $treeItem;

      }  echo json_encode($response);

       }

     }else {
    // user is not found with the credentials
     $response["error"] = TRUE;
    $response["error_msg"] = "Tree list view credentials are wrong. Please try  again!";
       echo json_encode($response);
       }
       $mysqli->close();
          }
```

Comment: What's the output you are getting now?

Comment: <!-- Hosting24 Analytics Code -->
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://stats.hosting24.com/count.php"></script>
<!-- End Of Analytics Code -->

Comment: What. Why would I care about the analytics. I'm asking you if you're getting any errors and what results are you getting.

Comment: I also tried this line. But I am able to get treeid, treelat & treelong of all the ids instead of filtering  $sq = "SELECT treeid, treelatitude, treelongitude FROM tree WHERE treecondition IN ('Healthy', 'Balanced', 'Imbalanced', 'Dangerous', 'Transplanted', 'Dieseased')";

Comment: Bharat - Bit of a long shot however; Are you maybe running the condition as 'healthy' rather than 'Healthy'? Usually case sensitivity is not an issue however it does depend how you have set up your database.

Answer (score 0):

I have tried and find answer from myself, even though I am beginner I have achieved to get result. I think PHP expert should look.

```
<?php

 define('__ROOT__', dirname(dirname(__FILE__))); 
 require_once(__ROOT__.'/public_html/Config.php');


  // Connecting to mysql database
   $mysqli = new mysqli(DB_HOST, DB_USER, DB_PASSWORD, DB_DATABASE);

  // json response array
  $response = array();




    if (isset($_POST['treecondition'])) {

      // receiving the post params

     $treecondition = $_POST['treecondition'];

     // get the tree details for google map marker


       if($stmt = $mysqli->prepare("SELECT treeid, treelatitude, treelongitude FROM tree WHERE treecondition = ?")){

     $stmt->bind_param("s", $treecondition);

     $stmt->execute();

     $stmt->store_result();

      $stmt->bind_result($treeid, $treelatitude, $treelongitude);


      if ($stmt->num_rows > 0) {


     while($tree = $stmt->fetch()) {



     $response[treeid] = $treeid;
     $response[treelatitude] = $treelatitude;
     $response[treelongitude] = $treelongitude;

     echo json_encode($response);



        }  

        }

        }else {
 // user is not found with the credentials
         $response["error"] = TRUE;
         $response["error_msg"] = "Tree list view credentials are wrong.  Please try again!";
         echo json_encode($response);
          }
        $mysqli->close();
         }
```